# How can I make an element not contribute to its parent div's scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there some way I can prevent a child div from contributing to its parent div's scrolling? I want the parent div to scroll on overflow, but there is only one child element I don't want that to apply to.

```
<div style="height:200px; overflow-y:scroll;">
    <div style="height:900px;" /> // don't cause parent to scroll on overflow
</div>
```

I basically want the `overflow-y:hidden;` functionality, but only for a certain child element.

Comment: try wrapping the child element inside another div and make it overflow hidden

Comment: Can you describe more thoroughly what result you would like? Images might help.